# WSDL web services consuming through Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, wsdl

I wanted to know is there any free open source code generator library available for doing "WSDL web services comsuming through Objective C" available?

I have used earlier "sudzc", but now they are paid :(.... I have also referred one blog for this http://www.webdosh.net/2012/05/converting-web-service-to-objective-c.html ...Both mention code generators are now paid.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I found that there is no free version of such generator. There are some libraries which are free but they are very old and are not updated from long time. Because of that I bought a subscription for SudzC. The problem with it is that there is no support. If you face a problem you have to deal it yourself (googling and asking here for example).